# Is there any way to replace 404 error messages with my company's logo, for instance, in web objects that don't load in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau

Have a dashboard with 4 web objects that load based on 4 dynamic URL actions. However, some selections have less than 4 images to load, in which case a 404 error occurs in the web object without a corresponding image. Trying to cover the missing 404 "not found" message with our logo for cases where there is no image to load.

Comment: do you control the webserver the content is loaded from? if not, do you use a proxy server?

Comment: @FrankThomas yes

Comment: in that case you should be able to replace the standard HTTP Error pages for whatever error code. the specifics will depend on your webserver type.